# Official Google Android OTA Links

Tags: nexus-5, ota-update, google

Today, I felt the right time to OTA-update my out of date Nexus 5 from 4.4.4 to 5.0. It worked pretty well and I found the required image within seconds. What I'm curious about is where to get the official list of official OTAs for Googles Nexus devices. Where does androidpit, androidcentral and the like get the links to the updates?

Thanks for hints!